# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to push my app to Heroku, however I'm getting this rather arbitrary error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -\
       /tmp/build_.../config/aws.yml
       /tmp/build_.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:39:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:39:in `open'
       /tmp/build_.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:39:in `unsafe_load_file'
       /tmp/build_.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:24:in `load_file_with_options'
       /tmp/build_.../config/initializers/aws.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
       /tmp/build_.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
       /tmp/build_.../vendor/
```

I have the proper keys in the `aws.yml` file so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, also it works fine locally.  I've tried removing the `/tmp` folder and letting Heroku re-generate it which also didn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: There might be some indentation spacing issue in your yml file, Proper indentation might help you. let me know if this helps, This helped me. Have deleted my comment as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `config/aws.yml` is in the right location and formed properly? Please check for all the references to it on your codebase.

When executing rake tasks the whole rails environment gets loaded. The error you mentioned arises if any file called by initializers or rake tasks doesn't exist or is not formed correctly.